# NPM ERROR installing React containing error shown below

Tags: reactjs, npm-install

> npm ERR! code EBUSY npm ERR! syscall unlink npm ERR! path
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache_cacache\tmp\fbcb3210 npm ERR!
> errno EBUSY npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch
> https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2Fpreset-modules: EBUSY: resource
> busy or locked, unlink
> 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache_cacache\tmp\fbcb3210'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-04-12T08_02_21_140Z-debug-0.log

I need help on fixing this issue hope anyone can help

Comment: Please mention what packages you are installing and add the full traceback of your error response.